# addEventListener("click".. in if statement executing all sub-options instead of just one

Tags: javascript

Trying to create simple game.

The idea is to create if statement for 10 different questions and every question will have 4 different answers. All good so far, however when I choose the first answer, instead of going to the next "else if" questions, it is stuck.

Any ideas on how to get this going ?

I was thinking about using Switch, however choosing the answers go with clicking a `<p>` text using `document.addEventListener("click" .....`

Here is the JS code I have so far:

```
<script>
var question = 1;


if (question === 1){

     document.getElementById("A").addEventListener("click", function(){
         document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = "Pozna!";
         document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "score = -300$";
         question +=1;
     });
     // ----------------------------------------------
     document.getElementById("B").addEventListener("click", function(){
         document.getElementById("B").innerHTML = "Sucker! You lost the game! Momchil took all your MONEY at once!";

         setTimeout(reLoad, 3000);
     });
     // ----------------------------------------------
     document.getElementById("C").addEventListener("click", function(){
         document.getElementById("C").innerHTML = "Sucker! You lost the game! Momchil took all your MONEY at once!";

         setTimeout(reLoad, 3000);
     });
     // ----------------------------------------------
     document.getElementById("D").addEventListener("click", function(){
         document.getElementById("D").innerHTML = "Sucker! You lost the game! Momchil took all your MONEY at once!";

         setTimeout(reLoad, 3000);
     });

   }

} else if (question === 2){

     document.getElementById("A").addEventListener("click", function(){
         document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = "Hello World";

         setTimeout(reLoad, 3000);
     });
     // ----------------------------------------------
     document.getElementById("B").addEventListener("click", function(){
         document.getElementById("B").innerHTML = "Hello World";

         setTimeout(reLoad, 3000);
     });
     // ----------------------------------------------
     document.getElementById("C").addEventListener("click", function(){
         document.getElementById("C").innerHTML = "Hello World";

         setTimeout(reLoad, 3000);
     });
     // ----------------------------------------------
     document.getElementById("D").addEventListener("click", function(){
         document.getElementById("D").innerHTML = "Hello World";

         setTimeout(reLoad, 3000);
     });

}
</script>
```

Comment: The series of `if` statements only runs once.

Comment: For all questions of this type, please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve]

Comment: Also add ONE event listener that looks at the question number and acts accordingly

Comment: `var actions = [ { money:-300, text : "Sucker" }, { money:100, text:"Well done, you earned 100"}]` then you can use `var act = actions[this.getAttribute("data-question")]; this.innerHTML=act.text; score += act.money; if (score<=0) ....`

Comment: I know guys that it is kind of messed up. The idea is not to make anything that complex - 10 questions with the if's counting question1 , question 2 etc.  However as you can see I would like to have 4 different actions in there, basically to allow the user to click on 4 different <p> texts (answers) and to make them do something and then to jump to the second questions. 

Here is a link to what I got so far to give you better idea:
https://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/newgame/momchil.html

Like a joke with one of my colleagues, however not sure how to jumo to the second If statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better start. You can add answers and do not need to reload, just replace the questions

Your position absolute does not work very well by the way

```js
var question = 0,
  score = 0,
  error = "Sucker! You lost the game! Momchil took all your MONEY at once!",
  ok = "Well done",
  questions = [{
      "Q": "1 What does the following sentence mean - 'The Horses are on the way!'",
      "answers": {
        "A": {
          "title": "And what if I am not the correct answer?",
          "money": -300,
          "text": "$O$ (Money) is on the way!"
        },
        "B": {
          "title": "Psst, hey .. it is the answer before me.",
          "money": -300,
          "text": "It's almost Todorov den."
        },
        "C": {
          "title": "JUST CLICK ME MAN!",
          "money": 100,
          "text": "Rohan will attack soon."
        },
        "D": {
          "title": "Sladko na Ostencata!",
          "money": -300,
          "text": "There are farmers nearby."
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Q": "2 What does the following sentence mean - 'The Horses are on the way!'",
      "answers": {
        "A": {
          "title": "2 And what if I am not the correct answer?",
          "money": -300,
          "text": "2 $O$ (Money) is on the way!"
        },
        "B": {
          "title": "2 Psst, hey .. it is the answer before me.",
          "money": -300,
          "text": "2 It's almost Todorov den."
        },
        "C": {
          "title": "2 JUST CLICK ME MAN!",
          "money": 100,
          "text": "2 Rohan will attack soon."
        },
        "D": {
          "title": "2 Sladko na Ostencata!",
          "money": -300,
          "text": "2 There are farmers nearby."
        }
      }
    }
  ];
function nextQ() {
  var q=questions[question], ids = ["A","B","C","D"],
  a = document.getElementById("A"),
  b = document.getElementById("B"),
  c = document.getElementById("C"),
  d = document.getElementById("D"),
  answers = q.answers;
  document.getElementById("Questions").innerHTML=q.Q;
  for (var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
    var id=ids[i],p = document.getElementById(id);
    p.title=answers[id].title;
    p.innerHTML=answers[id].text;
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
  var q = questions[question]
  for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    answers[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var act = questions[question].answers[this.id];
      score += act.money;
      document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "$" + score;
      if (act.money>0) { // positive amount will go to next question
        question += 1;
        this.innerHTML = ok;
      }
      else {
        this.innerHTML = error;
        // you can reset the score here since one error will be fatal
        // unless subsequent questions give more money
      }  
      setTimeout(nextQ,2000)
    });
  }
  nextQ(); // first question
}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background: #70bg32;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to left top, #e16525, #fbd109);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient( to left top, #e16525, #fbd109);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient( to left top, #e16525, #fbd109);
  background: -o-linear-gradient( to left top, #e16525, #fbd109);
  background: linear-gradient( to left top, #e16525, #fbd109);
}

#score {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1%;
  left: 42%;
}

#A {
  position: absolute;
  top: 72%;
  left: 12%;
}

#B {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 12%;
}

#C {
  position: absolute;
  top: 78%;
  left: 12%;
}

#D {
  position: absolute;
  top: 81%;
  left: 12%;
}

#img1 {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<p id="score">score = 0$</p>
<div style=" height:0; width:80%; padding-bottom:5%; background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);   position:absolute;   top:60%;   left:10%; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px;">
  <div id="Questions" style="padding-top: 15px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 15px;">

  </div>
</div>
<p class="answer" id="A" title=""></p>
<p class="answer" id="B" title=""></p>
<p class="answer" id="C" title=""></p>
<p class="answer" id="D" title=""></p>

<img id="img1" title="Mahni si mishkata ot men ue, papancho!" src="https://sarahkerrigan.biz/wpmtest/newgame/barovec.png" style=" position:absolute;   top:17%;   left:50%;" /></a>
```

Comment: That looks great, there is just 1 thing I need help with now :D , How to make different things to happen since if someone hits incorrect answer ? Like if A is correct and it should proceed with adding new questions etc (so far is ok) but if someone clicks on 2,3,4 text and it should be incorrect, how to add function to re-load the page and start over ? Thank you so much for checking on this!

Comment: Start over? With the same question 1 or with a new set of questions? You do not need to ever reload the page, just show a new question

Comment: Well , I am still learning, so decided to be with the same question 1 when it starts over:) Nothing complex yet as I am learning this step by step. The initial way of building this would have been great if the Switch statements were working with functions instead of just variables to check the addEventListner (if someone clicked any of the options) :D . Hope that helps a bit as I am still going through the options.

Comment: Maybe if there is a way with using Promise to check which option will be true once clicked ?

Comment: You can execute functions in a switch statement - just no need at all. I’ll show you two question in an hour or so

Comment: I think using promise is rather far above the level you need/want now

Comment: Sweet! Thanks a lot! Just learned something new here in using For :) That should do it perfectly.